# CSS border collapse issues in list menu

Tags: html, css, border

[image]

```
<li class="dropdown redq-fullwidth">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-flask"></i> <span> List </span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
            <!-- Content container to add padding -->
            <!-- <div class="redq-content"> -->
            <ul class="columns col-lg-4 col-sm-4 list-unstyled">
                <li>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="columns col-lg-4 col-sm-4 list-unstyled">
                <li>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="columns col-lg-4 col-sm-4 list-unstyled">
                <li>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- </div> -->
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>







.columns ul li {
  border: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
}
```

Now i'm having problem with the border issue . when i want to add li border then it's overriding with another one .whats the best way to remove the border overriding . it will be dynamic menu so i want a generic solution . thanks .

here is the link : http://yellowstring.net/mega-menu/

Comment: The link gives 404 error.